# android Read xml using simplexml

Tags: android, simple-framework

Im trying to read some xml generated by excel into Android. im using Simplexml to do this.

IM having trouble though getting the rows in to a list. the error i get is...
"org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'Row' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList"...

But Im not sure why. any ideas why?

The xml looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Worksheet ss:Name="DDDDDDDDDDDDDD">
      <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="20" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2672" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
         <Row>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">123</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="4">
               <Data ss:Type="Number">4</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="6">
               <Data ss:Type="String">sdinmsd</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="9">
               <Data ss:Type="String">dsddf</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="11">
               <Data ss:Type="String">sdsdsd 1AB</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">S06Cvcvvc28048</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Kdfdf</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">1dfd</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">835df</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">102df</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">393df</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">2012dfdf1005</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">New Custdfdfomer</Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
         <Row>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">123</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="4">
               <Data ss:Type="Number">4</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="6">
               <Data ss:Type="String">sdinmsd</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="9">
               <Data ss:Type="String">dsddf</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:Index="11">
               <Data ss:Type="String">sdsdsd 1AB</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">S06Cvcvvc28048</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Kdfdf</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">1dfd</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">835df</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">102df</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">393df</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">2012dfdf1005</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">New Custdfdfomer</Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
      </Table>
   </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

and my parse code looks like this...

```
    @Root(strict = false)
public class LocksXmlDisplay {

    @Element (name = "Worksheet")
    private Worksheet worksheet;

    public Worksheet getWorksheet() {
        return worksheet;
    }


    @Root(strict = false)
    public static class Worksheet {
        @Element (name = "Table")
        private Tables tables;
        public Tables gettables() {
            return tables;
        }

        @Root(strict = false)
        public static class Tables {

            @ElementList(name = "Row")
            private List<Row> list;
            public List getrows() {
                return list;
            }

            @Root(strict = false)
            public static class Row {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify that the `Row` list in `Table` is `inline=true`.

For example,

```
<?xml...>
<Hello>
    <World>
        <Magic name="Friendship"/>
        <Magic name="Love"/>
        <Magic name="Devotion"/>
        <Magic name="Miracle"/>
    </World>
</Hello>
```

Would be either

```
@Root(name="Hello")
public class Hello {
    @Element(name="World")
    private World world;

    //getter, setter
}

@Root(name="World")
public class World {
    @ElementList(type=Magic.class, inline=true)
    private List<Magic> magics;

    //getter, setter
}

@Root(name="Magic")
public class Magic {
    @Attribute(name="name")
    private String name;

    //getter, setter
}
```

or

```
@Root(name="Hello")
public class Hello {
    @ElementList(type=Magic.class, name="World", inline=false)
    private List<Magic> world;

    //getter, setter
}

@Root(name="Magic")
public class Magic {
    @Attribute(name="name")
    private String name;

    //getter, setter
}
```

Yours is the first case, as in `Table` contains an `inline list` of `Row`.